# ERROR in ./node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/Connection.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http'

Tags: angular, typescript, elasticsearch, angular6

I am working on an angular 6 project and I updated the version of elasticsearch from 6 to 7 on the server, after changing the code of the old API to use the new one, these errors occurred, does anyone have any idea how to correct?

The angular application is made on visual studio code and elasticsearch is on a linux server.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
// import { Clientex } from 'elasticsearch-browser';
import { Client } from '@elastic/elasticsearch';
// import * as elasticsearch from 'elasticsearch-browser';
// import { concatMapTo } from 'rxjs/operators';
// import { stringify } from '@angular/core/src/render3/util';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ElasticsearchService {

  private client: Client;
  // private clientex: Clientex;

  constructor() {
    if (!this.client) {
      this.connect();
    }
  }

  private connect() {
    /*this.client = new Client(
      {node: 'http://localhost:9200'}
    );*/
    this.client = new Client();
  }

  isAvailable(): Promise<any> {
    return this.client.ping({
    });
  }


  // tslint:disable-next-line:member-ordering
  private queryalldocs = {
    'query': {
      'match_all': {}
    }
  };

  getAllDocuments(_index, _type): any {
    this.client.search({
      index: _index,
      body: this.queryalldocs
    }, {
      ignore: [404]
    }, (err, { body, statusCode, headers, warnings }) => {
      if (err) { console.log(err); }
    });
}

  getAllDocumentsByKey(_index, _type, campo, valor) {
    const string = 'let match = {' + campo + ':' + valor + '}';
    return this.client.search({
      index: _index,
      type: _type,
      body: {
           // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
           eval(string) {}
      }
    });
  }

  createDocument(value: any) {
    // return this.client.index(value);
    this.client.create(value);
  }

}
```

ERRORS:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/Connection.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in
> 'C:\Users\ICARO\Desktop\projetos\pastas\xtr-social\node_modules@elastic\elasticsearch\lib'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/Connection.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in
> 'C:\Users\ICARO\Desktop\projetos\pastas\xtr-social\node_modules@elastic\elasticsearch\lib'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/Transport.js Module
> not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in
> 'C:\Users\ICARO\Desktop\projetos\pastas\xtr-social\node_modules@elastic\elasticsearch\lib'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/decompress-response/index.js Module not found:
> Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in
> 'C:\Users\ICARO\Desktop\projetos\pastas\xtr-social\node_modules\decompress-response'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/Transport.js Module
> not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in
> 'C:\Users\ICARO\Desktop\projetos\pastas\xtr-social\node_modules@elastic\elasticsearch\lib'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/decompress-response/index.js Module not found:
> Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in
> 'C:\Users\ICARO\Desktop\projetos\pastas\xtr-social\node_modules\decompress-response'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the elastic search documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/5.x/breaking-changes.html), all browser clients are handled via the elasticsearch-browser npm package:

> No more browser support, for that will be distributed via another module, @elastic/elasticsearch-browser. This module is intended for Node.js only.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to install elasticsearch-browser and then:

```
import { Client } from 'elasticsearch-browser';
```

Comment: the elasticsearch-browser is the elasticsearch version 6 API, this new version has changed the way you import
``angular
import {Client} from '@ elastic / elasticsearch';
``